# How to write inside a SPAN box with html special entity included with JavaScript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

To write

```
var string = "Hello There";
```

into

```
<span id="div_id">Hello There</span>
```

I used

```
  $("#div_id").text(string);
```

or this

```
$("#div_id").html(string);
```

But, It does not work if I have

```
var string = "Hello &amp; There";
```

It does not write to the string, it doesn't even show.

```
<span id="div_id">Hello & There</span>
```

Comment: use `.html(string)`

Comment: @Swati Op have tried `$("#div_id").html(string);`

Comment: Make sure you run the jquery code after you have created `<span id="div_id">Hello & There</span>`. Good idea is to wrap your jquery code in `$(document).ready(function() {})`

Comment: @Swati I know `.html()` works but OP has tried it so why would your suggestion work ?

Comment: @swati I have used that method did not not work

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen thank you for the clarification the method did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Using .html() does work (see snippet).  Maybe if you post the actual code you're running we can see what might be going wrong

```js
var string = 'Hello &amp; there';
$('#div_id').html(string);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="div_id"></span>
```